# filter/if-statement not properly working from the pipe?

Tags: powershell, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm piping a `Select-String | Select-Object` piece of code into a `sort` which outputs two columns. I had two files set up with two different sorts but wanted to try and combine them to one file using a conditional based on a `Read-Host` asking the user which sort they want to use (1 or 2).

I first tried an `if` statement within the pipe. As far as I can tell, I can't actually do an `if` inside of the pipe. Below is the statement. `$sort` is set by the user who types '1' for the first sort and anything else for the second. It produces an error about not recognizing `if`.

```
... | if ($sort -eq 1) {
    Sort-Object { $_.'Character' }
} else {
    Sort-Object { [double]$_.'Value' } –Descending
} | ...
```

I read about making a filter, so I also tried that with this piece of code and piped the code into the filter name 'sortby':

```
filter sortby {
    if ($sort -eq 1) {
        Sort-Object { $_.'Character' }
    } else {
        Sort-Object { [double]$_.'Value' } –Descending
    }
}
```

This goes through without an error, but the output actually comes out blank.

Is there a way I can successfully implement a conditional sort into the pipe without error? Or did I make a mistake?

Comment: `| Invoke-Command $( if($sort -eq 1) {{ sort-object { $_.'Character'  } }} else {{ sort-object { [double]$_.'Value'  } –Descending }} |`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use conditional statements in a pipeline.

Flip the logic around and store the parameters in a hashtable that you can use for splatting:

```
$sortArgs = @{
    Property = if($sort -eq 1){{ $_.Character }} else {{ $_.Value -as [double]}}
    Descending = $sort -ne 1
}

... | Sort-Object @sortArgs |...
```

Comment: You should double `{` and `}` in your `if` statement.

Comment: This worked after I doubled the brackets. Thank you!

Comment: @PetSerAl Thanks dude, nicely spotted